# Output messages with different intervals using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

Currently trying to implement the following task:
Have 10 messages being output to the console with different intervals, without having the previous ones stop working.

So in terms on my output I'm looking for something along the lines of

message0

message1

message0

message2

message0

message1

message3

Need to use threads for this task, and honestly don't really know what I'm doing.
The following code looks like something that would do it, but its output is just a mess and fails to produce the desired result.

```
public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Integer[] intarr = IntStream.range(3, 13).map((i)->i*1000).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        String[] strings = {
                "msg0", "msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4", 
                "msg5", "msg6", "msg7", "msg8", "msg9"

        };
        Task test = new Task(strings, intarr);

    }
    Spam(String[] msgs, Integer[]millis) throws InterruptedException {
        Map<String, Integer> msgsmap = IntStream.range(0, msgs.length).
                boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i-> msgs[i],i->millis[i]));
        for(String msg:msgs){
            Thread t = new Thread(()-> {
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(msgsmap.get(msg));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need to create the threads yourself, I would take advantage of `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
String[] strings = {
    "msg0", "msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4",
    "msg5", "msg6", "msg7", "msg8", "msg9"
};

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(strings.length);

IntStream.range(0, strings.length).forEach(i -> service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    System.out.println(strings[i]);
}, i + 3, i + 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

I was able to achieve the output you wanted once, but getting 10 threads to always cooperate isn't the easiest task.  However, you're free to change the delay to whatever you want.

If you need to create the threads yourself, I'll change my answer.

Comment: IMHO `ScheduledThreadPool` use a heap-based data structure to handle delayed tasks, so the number of worker threads doesn't matter as much as the number of tasks actually scheduled.

Comment: I'd appreciate you explaining how to create them myself, since I'd like to understand Threads from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to accomplish what I wanted in a more simple approach than I originally thought would be required. Code is the following:

```
public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Integer[] intarr = IntStream.range(1, 11).map((i) -> 2+i * 1000).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        String[] strings = {
                "msg0", "msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4", 
                "msg5", "msg6", "msg7", "msg8", "msg9"

        };
        Task test = new Task(strings, intarr);

    }

    Task(String[] messages, Integer[] intervals) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            runThread(messages[i], intervals[i]);
        }
    }

    private static void runThread(String message, Integer interval) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(interval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```